# font-face not working for safari

Tags: css, safari, font-face

I'm using @font-face rule in my project. Here's what I'm using in my css:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'BHoma';
    src: url('fonts/BHoma.eot?#') format('eot'),
    url('fonts/BHoma.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/BHoma.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

For all browsers is loading fine except for Safari. Fonts are in a folder called fonts that is located in the same folder as the css file and the language of the web site is Persian. I don't know how to debug this problem. Could anyone point out what needs to be done in order to make them work for Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Add @charset "UTF-8" to the top of cssfile.